# How do you use a complex, or multi part conditional with Adobe Document Generation?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe-documentgeneration

When using the Word add-in, I can create a condition on one value (if some property is greater than, less than, etc to some value) but I can't check *multiple* values. So for example: if name is "ray" and age > 48. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

The Word addin lets you do a lot with Document Generation, but can't handle every possible situation, this is one example of that. But remember that the tokens that the addin insert into your document is just simple text. You can edit that text as you see fit. So for example, if I insert a condition on my name:

```
{% conditional-section expr(name = 'ray') %} 

this person is ray

{% end-section %}
```

I can edit that by hand to add more conditions:

```
{% conditional-section expr(name = 'ray' and age > 48) %} 

this person is ray and he is over 48

{% end-section %}
```

You can use `and` and `or`.